# Salesforce rest query "join"

Tags: soql, php, rest

So I would like to know if a domain is in three or more tables
Normally I would do something like this to get one row

```
SELECT 
   c.Email, 
   a.Website, 
   l.Email as leadEmail 
FROM Contact as c 
JOIN Account as a ON a.contact_id = c.id 
JOIN Lead as l ON l.contact_id = c.id 
WHERE c.Email LIKE '%$domain'
```

Is there any possible way to do this as a single query in soql using relationship queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Email, ConvertedContact.Email, ConvertedAccount.WebSite FROM Lead WHERE ConvertedContact.Email LIKE '%domain'
```

This is the closest approximation you'll find to the actual SQL you provided. This will return all leads that were converted into contacts matching the given domain, and the website for that account.

Answer (score 0):

I think a [SOSL search](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/index_Left.htm) might be closest to what you're after. It behaves like the search box visible in the sidebar (or top of the page if you use Chatter). It won't help much with `Account.Website` though...

```
FIND {gmail.com} IN EMAIL FIELDS
RETURNING
    Contact(Id, LastName, Email, Account.Name),
    Lead(Id, LastName, Email)
LIMIT 10
```

A bit cheeky way would be to link them all up via Task/Event - if you're **sure** that each will have at least 1 activity...

```
SELECT Account.Website, Who.Email
FROM Event
WHERE Account.Website LIKE '%.com'
OR Who.Email LIKE '%.com'
LIMIT 10
```

If this search is important enough to warrant some preparations upfront you could always decide to make a small helper custom object and link to it... or maybe enable [tagging](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=tag_overview.htm&language=en_US) and tag the records?